# How can I delete some specific folders inside System Volume Information in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions

I have disabled System Restore, and I still have 1.2GB in a folder I down't want it there, C:\System Volume Information\SystemRestore\AppxStaging\Program Files\WindowsApps.

I cannot access this folder to delete it. I tried with TakeOwnership, said Success. But it cannot be deleted.

My HDD is very small, is an eMMC of only 28GB and every GB counts. I already moved many GB on an SSD, some of them hardlinked (folder junctions), some only by using shortcuts. Still there are many folders in Windows 10 (I'm reffering especially at Metro Apps) which I want to be able to easily remove.

Comment: You should be able to manage this from `Control panel` > `File History`

Comment: My file history is off already. The question is about Microsoft Apps which are pushed on my HDD without my consent.